# PouchDB and Cookie Authentication with CouchDB not actually logging in the user

Tags: javascript, couchdb, pouchdb

I have a node app that uses CouchDB for the database and PouchDB on the client. To log in, a request is sent to the node server, which authenticates the user's credentials with the CouchDB instance, before sending a cookie back to the client. The issue is, after restarting the browser and logging in, CouchDB sends a 401 Unauthorized response when Pouch tries to connect to the DB, and the browser brings up its default login popup. This happens even though the AuthSession cookie is in the browser.

The full error in Chrome is: `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 401 (Unauthorized) http://localhost:5984/user/?_nonce=rItPZR1fgbHrwn0a`

After entering the user credentials in the Chrome pop-up box and refreshing the page, it loads as normal. Going to the page listed and entering the user credentials gives various metadata about the user.

I assume this is happening because PouchDB doesn't actually use the AuthSession token sent by the node server, but the cookie that is given to it by CouchDB after the user is prompted with a 401. Is there any way to get around this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, as long as the cookie is getting set on the client, authentication should automatically be picked up by PouchDB. I have a plugin that demonstrates this: https://github.com/nolanlawson/pouchdb-authentication. You can use this plugin to talk directly to your CouchDB and it will definitely work. Maybe your Node proxy is not passing the cookie between PouchDB and CouchDB?

Comment: Hey, @nlawson. I'm using this plugin, talking directly to CouchDB but I'm having the same problem as described above: after restarting the browser, the user needs to manually login again. Seems like the Cookie is being unset when the browser is closed. Do you know if this have something to do with HttpOnly cookies or am I missing something?

Comment: Forget about it... Just went through a review of my CouchDB configs and I had the couch_httpd_auth allow_persistent_cookies set to false...

Answer (score 5):

You may need to intercept and modify PouchDB's `fetch` calls to add the [`credentials`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/fetch#Parameters) option, which you can easily do when you first construct the database object:

```
db = new PouchDB('https://yourcouch/yourdb', {
    fetch: (url, opts) => fetch(url, { ...opts, credentials: 'include' /* OR 'same-origin' */ })
});
```

Note that you'll want to set it to `same-origin` where appropriate, or `include` for cross origin / no origin requests.

Comment: Thank you! Contrary to the accepted answer, `PouchDB` doesn't seem to automatically pick up the cookie. This answer fixed it!

Comment: @kyw Glad it helped. I've just edited in a note to mention that for security reasons `same-origin` might be a better fit in some cases. The spec recently changed to make `same-origin` the default but it used to be `omit` and new spec isn't fully adopted yet.

Comment: @RobHogan I know this very late but just followed your answer and it does connect to couchbase but no document gets synced down. I do see stat like response in the couchbase response but no documents get synced down. This happened after i upgraded to v7.2.2. Full issue is here: https://github.com/pouchdb/pouchdb/issues/8151